# Attempt to read property "slug" on bool

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-blade

I have problem with display data from DB, i take it from database but display doesn't work. My model is empty. Thanks

> Route web.php

Route::get('/turnaje/{slug}', [RegionController::class, 'show']);

> show.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ url('turnaje/choose')}}" method="post">
        @csrf <!-- {{ csrf_field() }} -->
        <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

        <select name="region_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="vsetky-kraje">Všetky kraje</option>
            @foreach ($regions as $region)
                @foreach ($regions_list as $region_list)
                    <option value="{{ $region_list }}" {{ ($region_list->slug == $region->slug) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $region_list->title }}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </form>
```

> My RegionContoller

```
    public function show($slug)
{
    return view('tournaments.show', [
        'regions' => Region::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail(),
        'regions_list' => Region::all(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `$regions` is a single model instance (poorly named), you don't iterate a model

Comment: Can you give me more informations about it ? Thank you

Comment: `@foreach ($regions as $region)` - `$regions` is a single object, so you can't iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first foreach statement, and rename the variable to $region:

```
<form action="{{ url('turnaje/choose')}}" method="post">
        @csrf <!-- {{ csrf_field() }} -->
        <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

        <select name="region_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="vsetky-kraje">Všetky kraje</option>
           
                @foreach ($regions_list as $region_list)
                    <option value="{{ $region_list }}" {{ ($region_list->slug == $region->slug) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $region_list->title }}</option>
                @endforeach
            
        </select>
    </form>
```

in the controller:

```
    public function show($slug)

{
    return view('tournaments.show', [
        'region' => Region::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail(),
        'regions_list' => Region::all(),
    ]);
}
```